# How to Efficiently Query Large Remote Database

Tags: swift, database, github

I am planning a project that would involve hosting a very large CSV or JSON file on Github which I would want to be able to query.

The challenge is using a querying the database file, rather than downloading it for parsing.

How can I efficiently query a database file without server-side logic to parse the database for the client?

Comment: You can load the CSV file into an actual database, and then tune the query used to retrieve records (lines) from that table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks! Are you aware of any free solutions that would enable me to do this (I'm thinking of hosting an open source project that connects to this dataset)

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact, I do.  You can host the table on Amazon's RDS, using something like MySQL, which has a free tier.  A bit of work to setup, but once complete should run smoothly.

Comment: *"How can I efficiently query a database file without server-side logic to parse the database for the client?"* - you can't. CSV and JSON are not a database. Without server side logic (such as hosting a proper remote database), your only option with a remote static file is to download the remote file and parse it locally.